# ion-radio checked attribute is not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, radio-button

I need to check ion-radio when clicking on it's row. For some reason I can't use lable's width to fix this.
So I'm doing this:

```
const get_radio=document.getElementById('sendToSomeone') as HTMLInputElement;
console.log('get radio',get_radio);
get_radio.checked=true;
```

Logs show me this information:

```
ion-radio#sendToSomeone.md.interactive.hydrated.radio-checked {s-p: Array(0), s-rc: undefined, __zone_symbol__ionBlurfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__ionSelectfalse: Array(1), checked: true, …}
```

But it's not actually working and my radio button still is not checked.
here is my html code:

```
 <ion-radio-group value="all" (ionChange)="typeHandler($event)">
                        <ion-row style="height: 40%;">
                            <ion-item-divider style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none">
                                <ion-col>
                                    <ion-radio id="sendToAll" value="all" style="vertical-align: middle"></ion-radio>
                                </ion-col>
                            </ion-item-divider>

                        </ion-row>

                        <ion-row style="height: 10%"></ion-row>
                        <ion-row style="height: 90%">
                            <ion-item-divider style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none">
                                <ion-col>
                                    <ion-radio id ="sendToSomeone" value="checkbox"></ion-radio>
                                </ion-col>
                            </ion-item-divider>
                        </ion-row>
                    </ion-radio-group>
```

Comment: Can you also add your html code snipped?

Comment: just added it @laurisstepanovs